# How to generate validation rules on back-end side?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Client is webapp in browser, and back-end is written in Java (Spring Boot). Business flow is following: entity is requested from server → user fills the form → form is sent to back-end. The form should be validated both on front- and back-end sides. The validation rules depend on values inside the entity. I want to avoid duplication of code that is responsible for deriving the validation rules. I think the best way would be for back-end to add validation rules in response for requested entity, so that front-end could use them. Is there a common approach for such problem?

Comment: Yes. You can start with this article [Validating Form Input](https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/)

Comment: The problem with https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/ is with this approach the form is validated "lazily": when request for submission is sent to back-end. But I need the rules to be included in response and used by fron-end, so that fron-end does not send invalid form.

Comment: Validation Rules might not be the best place to avoid duplication of code. This is extremely critical in case of financial related validation rules, where you want both front end and back end validation rules to be separate. Again, it depend on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Altough I've never used it I can recommend you to get familiar with Open Api https://swagger.io/specification/

That is the specification which is implemented by the various engines: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/IMPLEMENTATIONS.md

Each engine provides code generation based on contract written in contract-file. It should be possible to achive some simple combinational validation. I'm pretty sure that if you want to get some sequential complex validtation which value is based on database state you will end up doing it by yourself.